# How to place a custom label on a data point on a chart in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I know this is a simple one, maybe just having trouble asking the question(searching for this same question.)
Simple line of code:

```
Chart1.Series("Drawing").Points.AddXY((xcoord(ya, yb)), ((ycoord(ya, yb))))
```

How do I add a custom label to this point on the chart such as "1" or "Point 1."?

Comment: Please format your language properly. So the code line is actually marked as code. Also do not forget to meantion what kind of classes you are using. There are many different charting libraries one could use.

Comment: It could help if you included a screenshot of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you must know what is the target Point.

-Either :

```
    Dim targetPoint As Int32 = 5
    Chart1.Series("Drawing").Points.Item(targetPoint)......
    ' where targetPoint is a valid n-th index of the point.
```

-or :

```
    Dim targetPoint As Int32
    targetPoint = Chart1.Series("Drawing").Points.AddXY(....)
```

---

Then, use that `targetPoint` to edit the Label :

```
    Chart1.Series("Drawing").Points.Item(targetPoint).Label = "lalalilala"
```